# Hyper-V VM failing to start

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I use an older version of windows for some dev/testing purposes using hyper-v on my win 10 machine. I recently moved the .vhdx file from one drive to another as I needed some space for other work. I then moved back the .vhdx file to its original location but I am now getting this error. Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

or this if I try without disabling checkpoint

[image]

Comment: found the solution here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/137175/hyper-v-vm-failed-to-start.html?childToView=138479#answer-138479

Comment: please add the answer to your question yourself and mark it as such. as the link may change or be moved it's best practice to add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Right click on the VHD file, click properties. On the General tab, click Advanced and check if the Compress or Encrypt is selected.

[image]